# curl needs to send '\r\n' - need transformation of a working solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, http-post

I need a transformation of the following working curl command:

```
curl --data-binary @"data.txt" http://www.example.com/request.asp
```

The data.txt includes this:

```
foo=bar
parameter1=4711
parameter2=4712
```

The key is I need to send the linebreaks and they are \r\n. Its working with the file because it has the right encoding but how do I manage to get this curl command run without the file? So a 1-liner sending the parameters with the correct \r\n on end of each.

All my tests with different URL encoding, etc. didn't work. I never got the same result like with the file.

I need this information because I have serious trouble to get this post run on my Ruby on Rails App using net/http.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve it is to generate the binary stream with something on the fly, like the printf command, and have curl read the data from stdin:

```
printf 'foo=bar\r\nparameter1=4711\r\nparameter2=4712' | curl --data-binary @- http://example.com
```

Comment: Thanks, its works that way! I will go for another question but more Rails related.